# Is the assumption of risks proportionality required when we assessing the difference of two KM branches (curves)?

Tags: r, survival, hazard

There are two KM branches (curves) (for example, for male and female). Can I use a log-rank test if the assumption of risk proportionality is not satisfied?
P.S. I checked this with the code: plot(Y~sex, fun="cloglog")

Answer (score 1):

Under the null hypothesis of no difference between the survival curves of, e.g., males and females, the hazard functions are proportional (actually they are equal). Therefore, the log-rank test has the nominal Type I error of 5% when you decide to reject at significance level of 5%.

Under the alternative hypothesis when there are differences between the survival curves of males and females, the log-rank test is most powerful (i.e., it has the highest chance of finding a statistical significant difference) when the hazard functions are proportional. If there are mild violations of the proportional hazards assumption, there are alternative tests that can be a bit more powerful, for example the Gehan-Wilcoxon test.

If you work in R and the **survival** package, both the log-rank and Gehan-Wilcoxon tests are available in the `survdiff()` function by suitably setting the `rho` argument.

Comment: Thank you Dimitris! (An example "male-female" is really bad.)